# A just created zip file by powershell is used by another process

Tags: powershell, zip

My powershell script is copying files to several folders from one input folder. I copy files but also files in sub folders into this input folder. At the end of the script (if all files are copied to other folders) I want to zip all files from the input folder into one zip file:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 
"\\networkdrive\RawData\1_DataRetrieved*" - 
 Recurse 

#copy ResponseTimes files to Response times data folders:
$files | Where-Object Name -Like "*ResponseTimes*" | Copy-Item -Destination 
"\\networkdrive\ResponseTimes\RawData_Field\2_ActionData" -Verbose

#zip all files from input folder into one zip file
$compress = @{
Path = "\\networkdrive\RawData\1_DataRetrieved\*" 
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = "\\networkdrive\_Archive\Archive_DataRetrieved\Archive_DataRetrieved $(get- 
date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss).zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress -Verbose
```

This will not always succeed, it seems as if there are large files (0-20MB) in sub folders in the input folder, I get the error message below. Small files (couple of kb), not in subfolders that are in the input folder, will result into a zip file.

VERBOSE: The partially created archive file
'\eubelccfs01\REGIONAL\Drachten\R&D\SHM\RawData
_Archive\Archive_DataRetrieved\Archive_DataRetrieved 2023-05-
09_045227.zip' is deleted as it is not usable.

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The 
process cannot access the 
file '\\networkdrive\RawData\_Archive\Archive_DataRetrieved\Archive_DataRetrieved 2023-05- 
09_080317.zip' because it is being used by another process."
At   
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.
PowerShell.Archive.psm1:729 char:30
   + ... ileStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $ ...
   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
   ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand}
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: This might be wrong but could you try putting a sleep after the copy-item and before compress-archive. something like sleep 10000. I am thinking it might need time to release the resources.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it did not help. I did discover, however, that the zip process is started (also before I added the sleep command): several files are added to the zip file, but then the zip file is removed ('VERBOSE: The partially created archive file '\\networkdrive\RawData\_Archive\Archive_DataRetrieved\Archive_DataRetrieved 2023-05-09_045227.zip' is deleted as it is not usable.) and then the error message '...is used by another process' is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestion from @Hayco you could also try adding a combination of do/while and try/catch to try it, wait a while, try again. For instance

```
do{
    $Failed = $false
    Try{
        Compress-Archive @compress -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
    } 
    catch { 
        $Failed = $true 
        write-host "Sleeping for 60 seconds and trying again"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
} while ($Failed)
```

Which should try doing the Compress-Archive, if it fails sleep for 60 seconds and then try again until successfully.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this addition. I have come up with a simple solution: do the archiving before the copying. This seems to work, the zip file is now not 'self-locked' (although there is no reason why it should not work after the copying, since the zip process is started every time, but after a few files ends in the error)

Comment: Archiving before copying did not work eventually, I think it is due to the number or size of files (my last run had 381 files, in 42 folders, total 118 MB).

Comment: @Hayco That does sound plausible (though you'd think it should just work). I've had issues when working with large numbers of files in the past. Knocking up a log archive script for a folder that hadn't been touched in ages, and it would just never complete or even give signs of working. Manually archived the oldest logs to reduce the number and it then just started working as expected again. I sometimes end up just getting PS to call Winrar/7zip and them compress the files, rather than use the PS method that doesn't always cope when there's lots to do.